# PhpMyAdmin auto refresh MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I Run update or select query within phpmyadmin local page, I get table results pop up with the "GO" button. But for using *.php file from a server I have to use refresh button to see the newly incoming data on my table, create view didn't help, or I may be missing something. How can I view them like an auto refresh/update style! any help?

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) {

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `tabl_nam` (
                `col_1` ,
                `col_2`
                 )
                VALUES ('" . $data[0]. "', '" . $data[1] . "')";
    }
mysqli_query($link,$sql2);
$sql1 = "UPDATE `tabl_nam` SET `col_1`= '" . $data[0]. "',`col_2`='" . $data[1]. "'";
//$sql1 = "SELECT `col_1`, `col_2` FROM `Cr_view` WHERE 1"; 

//"Cr_view" is  my create view table on phpmyadmin
//$sql1 = "SELECT `col_1`, `col_2` FROM `Cr_view` WHERE 1";//I tried 'SELECT' query as well                 
mysqli_query($link,$sql1);
mysqli_close($link);      

//both the above select and update queries worked on phpmyadmin console
```

If not PhpMyAdmin, is there any solution (S.W or code or query)for auto updating the view when uploading a new data for at least a single table.

Comment: Because phpMyAdmin uses AJAX/JQuery requests to pull the data without having to refresh the page, here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643644/get-data-from-mysql-database-using-php-and-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 4):

Create a bookmark with this "address":

`javascript:setInterval(function() { $('a:contains("Refresh")').click(); }, 10000);`

After opening the phpMyAdmin, click on this bookmark (or run this snippet directly from URL bar) and from now, tables will be auro-refreshed every 10 seconds.

Comment: I added it as Tempermonkey script to make it .

Comment: my Tempermonkey version https://gist.github.com/senpl/552683d28e6a97293f5f1e9de486e7cd#file-phpmyadminrefresh-js for german version but could be changed to Refresh.

Answer (score 1):

If the above bookmarklet doesn't work try this one. It fixes the browser navigating to a page instead of clicking the Refresh link (at least in Firefox).

```
javascript:var _x=setInterval(function(){$('a:contains("Refresh")').click();},10000);
```