# How to auto refresh database data in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

How do I auto-refresh database data in PHPMyAdmin? Because if we want to display updated database we have to refresh it manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PhpMyAdmin auto refresh MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467307/phpmyadmin-auto-refresh-mysql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For MySql Table**
Create a bookmark with this "admin":

```
javascript:setInterval(function() { $('a:contains("Refresh")').click(); }, 10000);
```

1.Open phpMyAdmin,
2.Click on this bookmark (or run this snippet directly from URL bar)
3.Tables will be auto-refreshed every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to the accepted solution of this question: [How do I refresh a DIV content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801650/how-do-i-refresh-a-div-content/33801831)

or this: [PhpMyAdmin auto refresh MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467307/phpmyadmin-auto-refresh-mysql-table)

I apologize if it still isnt what you require.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin is not meant to automatically refresh the results page (imagine a situation of trying to read or edit a Browse page where new results are being inserted every few seconds, this would be quite frustrating or completely unusable). The solution linked to by virtualpanda (and copied here from there by sai) might be the best you can do for phpMyAdmin.

For refreshing a query presented in phpMyAdmin, look for the `Refresh` text under the SQL command, above the results page. This is the provided way of updating even a complex query.

Remember that phpMyAdmin is meant as an administrative interface; if you're displaying data to the end user you should write some custom solution where you can refresh the data if you prefer.