# How to determine the cause of AJAX delay on my site?

Tags: php, ajax, server

I have an AJAX search facility on my website, and when I search something in the live site, until the results come (tables have no more than 20 entries) the page freezes for a short period of time, nowhere else is clickable on the website but it doesn't freeze the computer. I can click other tabs on the browser etc.

I am using this query in MySQL/InnoDB, which takes 0.031 sec to run:

```
select * from members m where
    memberID LIKE '%$keyword%' OR
    memberName LIKE '%$keyword%' AND
    memberTypeID=2;
```

I think it is a bit related with the connection to the server and a bit related with the server's performance. How can I improve this?

I use Bootstrap pagination to put all the data in a paginated table that has search, sort, page, amount of entries per page options and all of these are done on client side.

Comment: Is this a site presently running on your local machine? If the heavy lifting to do the search is putting load on your own CPU, remember that once you go live, that load will be placed on a different server, and the CPU is likely to be better than your development machine's processor anyway.

Comment: How long is this short period of time? What is the query you are running that causes it? What database server are you using?

Comment: halfer, it is not my own CPU. It is a live server. The query is something like: "select * from members m where memberID LIKE '%$keyword%' OR memberName LIKE '%$keyword%' AND memberTypeID=2;". I'm using MySQL server along with the php server(both running on the same server) Engine is InnoDB...

Comment: How long does that take to run, exactly)? LIKE with wildcards in front is _relatively_ slow, but not if you only have 20 rows in your tables. (Note: try this in the MySQL console in your live environment, it will time it for you).

Comment: the query took 0.031 seconds when I run the sql on MySQL Workbench. On the website, the freeze takes 2-3 seconds.

Comment: OK, so it's definitely not this query (3 hundredths of a second is not noticeable). Does the operation use AJAX to return/render results? How much data is returned, in kilobytes? Is there a lot?

Comment: Well, the returned data is in bytes I would say. But after the results are returned, I use Bootstrap pagination to put all the data in a paginated table that has search, sort, page, amount of entries per page options and all of these are done on client side. That might just be the delay.

Comment: Yes, that does sound like the problem - on the front end. Use a timer in JavaScript to determine the delay between receiving the AJAX data and finishing rendering it.

Comment: There is nothing I can really do about it. I'll disable some options, so it renders the data faster on client side. Thanks for all the help, much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why there is nothing that can be done about it - JavaScript can often be optimised. For starters, you could render using timers/callbacks - changes would be slower to appear, but the approach would avoid the freezing of the UI you've described.

Comment: I simply have no idea how to do what you said :)

Comment: Can we see the relevant bit of your present AJAX handler in JavaScript, so we can see what it is doing when it successfully gets a server reply?

Comment: This is the file that makes the live search http://pastebin.com/wVXFCa8A and this is the file that returns the live search results in a paginated table http://pastebin.com/6XRruCWv

Comment: Great - please edit them into the question - use the code button to format them. We don't encourage pastebins here, as links break, and someone wanting to read the question after that point won't be able to.

Comment: (Your `search.php` has a SQL injection vulnerability that needs fixing).

Comment: I'm aware of that, all my pages have SQL injection vulnerability atm. Those will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact method to measure exactly how powerful your server should be, but you can always predict things.

**Solution 1:**
If you are using complex database queries you should go for a dedicated powerful server.

**Solution 2:** You could use ajax asynchronous call to database so other things keep on loading and does not hangs up the page.

More about AJAX call: [Get data from mysql database using php and jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643644/get-data-from-mysql-database-using-php-and-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I'll focus on the Solution 2. Where do you think I can start about learning this "asynchronous" ajax calls?

Comment: I just found out that ajax is async by default and I'm not specifying it to be sync.

Comment: You can start learning using [link](http://w3schools.com) or many other web sources.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it depends on two things.

- `Size` of Website.( Each Time someone will open website, your bandwidth
  will be consumed)
- `Memory` used by `SQL` queries.(Suppose you have
  100,000 records in a table, a simple `SELECT`
  query wont consume that much, but it your query is complex, contains
  joins and not optimized properly then it may consume a lot)

According to My Experience. 
A 2MB website , with 4 tables and approximately 50,000 records each. Can you work fine on Shared Hosting if you have less than 50 user in an **hour**.

Anything above that, you need Virtual Private server. (This is not fixed few website provide very powerful shared hosting, but price is also high)

In your case i guess you are using a free hosting or your localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll consider the ideas you gave. It is not localhost, but I can say it is a shared host and can assume that it is not so powerful. But the query is not so complicated and the tables don't have that many entries. The query took 0.031 seconds when I run the sql on the db environment directly.