# Ajax Jequery Post without Form tag & without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have a page to post data via ajax jquery without refresh an without form tag. N validate via snackbar.

I know that this is possible using jQuery and AJAX, but I'm not really experienced in one of these languages. Anyone got an idea how to solve this?

its my button funtion:

```
<input type="text" id="nikpemohon">
<input type="text" id="namapemohon">
<button id="tombolsimpan" onclick="validate()"></button>`
```

here my js:

```
function validate() {
    var regExnamapemohon = /^[a-zA-Z .'-]+$/;

    var values = {
        'nikpemohon': document.getElementById('nikpemohon').value,
        'namapemohon': document.getElementById('namapemohon').value,
    };

    if(document.getElementById('nikpemohon').value == "" || document.getElementById('nikpemohon').value == null || document.getElementById('nikpemohon').value == undefined || document.getElementById('nikpemohon').value.length < 16 ) {
        //get the snackbar
        var notification = document.querySelector('.mdl-js-snackbar');
        //creating data for snackbar notification
        var data = {
            message: 'Isi NIK dengan benar. Contoh: 6108011234567890',
            timeout: 4000
        }
        //pushing the notification to the screen
        notification.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
        document.getElementById('nikpemohon').focus();
    } else if (document.getElementById('namapemohon').value == "" || document.getElementById('namapemohon').value == null || document.getElementById('namapemohon').value == undefined || !regExnamapemohon.test(document.getElementById('namapemohon').value) )  {
        //get the snackbar
        var notification = document.querySelector('.mdl-js-snackbar');
        //creating data for snackbar notification
        var data = {
            message: 'Isi Nama Lengkap hanya dengan huruf abjad saja, tanpa Penulisan Gelar. Contoh: Matius, Markus atau Darius',
            timeout: 4000
        }
        //pushing the notification to the screen
        notification.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(data);
        document.getElementById('namapemohon').focus();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ktp_post.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: values,
        }); 
    }
}
```

this my ktp_post.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['tombolsimpan'])){ 

$nikpemohon = strtoupper($_POST['nikpemohon']);
$namapemohon = strtoupper($_POST['namapemohon']);

$sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO katimpus (nikpemohon, namapemohon)Values('{$nikpemohon}', '{$namapemohon}')");}
```

please help here. two days spent for this error. I cannot Post the data to mysql database..

Comment: what's your error?

Comment: Cant post to mysql database

Comment: paste your error please

Comment: no I mean with this code, it not post any data into database sir.

Comment: have you checked the network setting in your dev tools to see if the ajax file is being called?

Comment: any error in your browser console? any error in your php log file?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: No error on console. [SS](http://image.prntscr.com/image/54731f5a3c914dc39c62b541af9abbe3.png)

Comment: How to see ajax respone / request in chrome?

Comment: You didn't set value for `tombolsimpan` in your `values `parameter of jQuery ajax request. So the php function doesn't work. :)

Comment: `(function (json_args) {
 var args = JSON.parse(unescape(json_args));
 console[args[0]].apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1));
})('%5B%22groupCollapsed%22%2C%22XHR%20Loaded%20%28ktp_post.php%20-%20200%20OK%20-%20250.99999999656575ms%20-%20239B%29%22%5D');` thats my error i think

Comment: this [screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/0ab2c0204c11422e95f39f42c0490913.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used proper value for your button
Try like this:

`<form method='post'>`
`<input type="text" id="nikpemohon">`
`<input type="text" id="namapemohon">`
`<input type="button" id="tombolsimpan" value="tombolsimpan" onclick="validate()"/>`
`</form>`

Comment: No. I not go with form element. with form element I usualy fine. but, this bout not using form element.

Comment: In you code you are checking `if(isset($_POST['tombolsimpan']))` and you are not getting that value because it is not set...

Comment: so, without form element, I just delete isset on php procces?

Comment: I you really want to check `isset($_POST['tombolsimpan'])` you have to use like this  var values = {
        'nikpemohon': document.getElementById('nikpemohon').value,
        'namapemohon': document.getElementById('namapemohon').value,
    };

Comment: in your value array use one more element i.e. `tombolsimpan: anyValue` so that issset method check your post data

Comment: any example for doing that?
How with PDO maybe?

Comment: ok. to be clear. that example is used Form element. I dont want use form element because my empty input elemet validated by Snackbar. If I use form element, then button function `validate()` not work. button push submit data without being validate by snackbar.

Answer (score 0):

i fix by delete `if(isset($_POST['tombolsimpan'])){` & `}` on .php process