# Fetch data from database in php through AJAX,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**index.php**

First I create a connection with the database, I design table through `<td>` and `<tr>`, I create a variable `$action` to get data through AJAX. I use `mysqli_fetch_array` to fetch data from the database.

```
<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC"); // mysql_query is deprecated

// using mysqli_query instead
?>

<html>
<head>  
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/datatables.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="DataTables/datatables.js"></script>

    <script src="style/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <script src="style/datatable.js"></script>

    <script src="DataTables/DataTables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="DataTables/DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>   
</head>

<body>
<a href="add.html">Add New Data</a><br/><br/>
<table id="datatable" class="display" width='100%' border=0>
    <thead>
        <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Update</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
    //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 

    //$action=$_POST["action"];
    //if($action=='showroom')   
    {
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$res['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['age']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['email']."</td>";  
        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";       
    }
    }
    ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Add.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Data</title>
    <script src="style/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="style/insert.js"></script>
    <script src="style/view.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <br/><br/>  
    <table bgcolor="orange" align="center" width="25%" border="0">
        <tr> 
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Age</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" value="Add"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    

    <button type="button" id="submitBtn">Show All</button>
    <div id="content"></div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**view.js**

I fetch data from the database. I use the `show_all()` function after that I call `$.ajax`, `data`, `url`, `type`, `success` function. The first time I try to fetch data from the database through AJAX.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#submitBtn').click(function() {

        debugger;

        $.ajax({
            //data :{action: "showroom"},
            url  :"index.php", //php page URL where we post this data to view from database
            type :'POST',
            success: function(data){
                $("#content").html(data);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to look around how ajax works ?

Comment: Have u tried to goggle the title of your question?

Comment: Hi. Your ajax code is fine, just wrap action in double quotes and try.  data :{"action": "showroom"} ,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get data from mysql database using php and jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643644/get-data-from-mysql-database-using-php-and-jquery-ajax)

Comment: You don't need the `<html>`,`<body>`,`<head>` tags on the php file, you just want the data, clean.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\CRUD\index.php on line 31  Iam facing this error

Comment: I did My data i properly inserted through AJAX, but can you help me for explain some thing. like meaning of "data :{action: "showroom"}, " and $action=$_POST["action"];

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, when you post a question, take care of every aspect: how the sentences are written, how the code is formatted, if the punctuation is correct. Otherwise, the other users will spend double the time to read and understand it. We are glad to help you here, but you can't abuse our time and effort. Please read [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**index.php**

<?php
//including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

//fetching data in descending order (lastest entry first)
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC"); // mysql_query is deprecated


 // using mysqli_query instead
?>

<html>
<head>  
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/datatables.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="DataTables/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="DataTables/datatables.js"></script>

    <script src="style/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>

    <script src="style/datatable.js"></script>

    <script src="DataTables/DataTables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="DataTables/DataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>





</head>

<body>
<a href="add.html">Add New Data</a><br/><br/>

    <table id="datatable" class="display" width='100%' border=0>
    <thead>
    <tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>Update</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
    //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 

    //$action=$_POST["action"];
    //if($action=='showroom')

    {
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$res['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['age']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['email']."</td>";  
        echo "<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";       
    }
    }
    ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>


**add.html**

<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Data</title>
    <script src="style/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="style/insert.js"></script>
    <script src="style/view.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <a href="index.php">Home</a>



    <br/><br/>


        <table bgcolor="orange" align="center" width="25%" border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Age</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" value="Add"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <button type="button" id="submitBtn">Show All</button>
        <div id="content"></div>


</body>
</html>

**view.js**

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#submitBtn').click(function()
    {
        debugger;



        $.ajax({
            //data :{action: "showroom"},
            url  :"index.php", //php page URL where we post this data to view from database
            type :'POST',
            success: function(data){



                $("#content").html(data);

                }

            });



    }); 
});


**datatable.js**


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable( {

    } );
} );
```

Comment: I did this in my level now its working you can fetch the data from database through AJAX and bind it to datatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        data :{"action": "showroom"} ,
        url  :"index.php", 
        type :'POST',
        success: function(data){
           $("#content").html(data);
        }
        });
   }
```

Comment: Sir I implemented your suggestion but getting below error 
Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\CRUD\index.php on line 31 Iam facing this error –

Comment: I did My data i properly inserted through AJAX, but can you help me for explain some thing. like meaning of "data :{action: "showroom"}, " and $action=$_POST["action"];

Comment: yes data element contain all values which we are posting to url. Here action is the key as same in form as name and showroom is the value of action key.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you. I use this to get data from the database.

```js
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "process.php",
   success: function(data) {
      if (data != "null") {
         $('#div_id').html(data)
      } else {
         $('#div_id').html('<p>No Data found</p>')
      }
   }
})
```

you can check this for complete tutorial.h[ow to fetch data from database in php using ajax with example](https://easyitschool.com/how-to-fetch-data-from-database-in-php-using-ajax-with-example/)