# Fetch data from mysql database into datatable using jquery

Tags: datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

I have developed a mysql database and a php code. In php code i am using jQuery (ajax call) to fetch the data from the database. In html file i have printed datatable's table head only. Rest data i want to fetch from the database. code is given:

---

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="container box">
     <div class="table-responsive">
            <div id="alert_message"></div>
            <table id="example" class="display">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Student ID</th>
                     <th>Student Name</th>
                     <th>Email ID</th>
                     <th>Mobile</th>
                     <th>Status</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
```

---

**jQuery CODE:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "fetch.php",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

**fetch.php**

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lib");
$sql = "SELECT StudentId, FullName, EmailId, MobileNumber, Status  FROM tblstudents";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

$json_array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $json_array[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json_array);
?>
```

---

Still the data is not printed in the datatable. What changes are necessary in jQuery?

Comment: check this if useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444582/fetch-data-from-database-in-php-through-ajax

Comment: Debug the output, check if there are server-side errors.

Comment: have you checked that the returned JSON is as you expected, and is in a format expected by the plugin? Are there any errors in the PHP logs, or in your console? You need to do some basic debugging, by the looks of it...

Comment: I have checked the json respond. its responding all the data from the database according to the sql query correctly

Comment: Ok but is that what DataTables is expecting? You didn't answer the second part of my question. I would imagine it expects data in a particular format? What about error messages or warnings?

Comment: data tables are expecting 5 columns data of the database. json is printing all the data but it is not printed in the data tables. please suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery Datatables, not only you can fetch data from ajax call. you can manage page ordering, searching as well.

first of all you have to modify your javascript like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "fetch.php",
                "type": "post"
            },
                error: function () {  // error handling code
                    $("#example").css("display", "none");
                }
        });
    });
```

Then as you can see in the browsers Developer Tools -> Network tap, all the parameters that wanted for searching, sorting and ordering will be pass trough the ajax call.

you can see it by print_r($_POST) in the ajax page (in your case fetch.php) and viewing it on ajax respond in the browsers Developer Tools -> Network tap.

you can collect all of that as follows,

```
    $order_by = $_POST['order']; // This array contains order information of clicked column
    $search = $_POST['search']['value']; // This array contains search value information datatable
    $start = $_POST['start']; // start limit of data
    $length = $_POST['length']; // end limit of data
    $order_type = $order_by[0]['dir'];
    if ($order_by[0]['column']==0){
        $order_column = "table_column_name_of_the_first_column_in_the_datatable";
    } elseif ($order_by[0]['column']==1){
        $order_column = "table_column_name_of_the_second_column_in_the_datatable";
    }
```

then you can construct the query as follows,

```
if ($search!='' || $search!=NULL) {
    $str = "WHERE column_name_to_search LIKE '%$search%' OR column_name_to_search LIKE '%$search%' ";
} else {
    $str = "";
}
$data[][] = array(); 
$i = 0;
$sql = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM your_table $str ORDER BY $order_column $order_type LIMIT $start,$length");
while ($row_1 = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[$i] = array($row_1['column_1'],$row_1['column_2']);
    $i++;
}
```

then to get total record count you can do as follows,

```
$sql_2 = $connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS all_count FROM your_table $str");
$row_2 = $sql_2->fetch_assoc();
$totalRecords = $row_2['all_count'];
if ($totalRecords==0){
    $data = array();
}
```

finally construct the json out put that will be sent to the front view.

```
$json_data = array(
    "draw"            => intval( $_POST['draw'] ),
    "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalRecords ),
    "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalRecords),
    "data"            => $data   // total data array
);
$json_data = json_encode($json_data);
echo $json_data;
```

That will work.

Comment: you have written 5 para of coding. where would be the papa-2,3 and 4 would be placed? In fetch.php or in the same file where jQuery is written?

Comment: obviously, in fetch.php except that javascript.

Comment: no its not working. its giving too much errors pls give some other solution

Comment: did you replace column names and table names in the code?

Comment: what is the error you getting? do you familiar working with ajax based developments?

Comment: if i write your code in fetch.php file then i am getting following errors:                

Notice: Undefined index: order in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib\fetch.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib\fetch.php on line 8


Notice: Undefined index: start in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib\fetch.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: length in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib\fetch.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib\fetch.php on line 33

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Lib\fetch.php on line 33

Comment: and i am not famalier with the ajax based developmet.

Comment: can you shear your files including database.

Comment: Only issue there is you didn't replace db connection right. replace '$connection' to your db connection. that is '$con'.

Comment: what should be the value of order, search, start, length which you have written in second para?

Comment: They are automatically passed by datables plugin. order will pass what you should put on ORDER BY clause (column name,ASC or DESC). search is that your searching query that you type in datatable search. start and length that define how many rows to show in datatable page. it used in LIMIT $start, $length in the query.

Comment: ok. as you said earlier, i have changed $con to $connection. also i have mailed you the entire code. please review it and then find the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177712/discussion-between-deepak-tomar-and-lahiru-madusanka).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late, but I used the exact same code as you (thanks for that by the way!), and what made it work for me is to simply add to the JQuery code:

dataSrc = ''       (after url = '...')

so that DataTables knows that it's loading an array. Putting that in made the code work fine!